# How to add/put click event for the element which is in Ext.XTemplate in combobox EXT JS?

Tags: extjs, combobox

I am trying to add click event to the element in combobox Ext js. Below is my code.

`tpl : new Ext.XTemplate('<div id = "selectAll" class="sel-all" style="padding:0 10px; cursor:pointer"><input type="checkbox">SELECT ALL</input></div>','<tpl for=".">', '<div class="x-boundlist-item">', '<input type="checkbox" />', '{somename}', '</div>', '</tpl>')`

In above, I need to select the first div with SELECT ALL text and add a click event for that. I am able to get that by this Ext.get('select'). But it will only give data when it is put under blur event or select event. Otherwise it gives null.

All i want is i want to get that element and need to add click event . Like below
`selectAll.onclick (){.....MY CODE...}` Once i clicked on that select all inbox,all the data should be selected in store data.

Could you please kindly help me out.
**NOTE: This Elements is defined inside the Panel**

My code will give the drop down like below once click on the combobox

SELECT ALL
data1
data2
data3
etc..
All will comes with check box. If i click on the data1, it will be selected(Which is working fine. Because those data are comes from store).But when i SELECT ALL it should select all the data.All check box should be selected and added the that box except SELECT ALL.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You could add a listener to your parent Component, like this:

```
    listeners: {
        click: {
            element: 'el',
            delegate: 'div.sel-all',
            preventDefault: true,
            scope: me,
            fn: function(el, target) {
            }
        }
    }
```

I created a sencha fiddle for you to try out: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3acs